# Can't assign a value to object of my custom class, that shall behave like a matrix

Tags: c++

I have custom class, that behaves like matrix. Everything works well, except assigning a value from other instance of the same class.

So I can do stuff like:

```
Matrix a(5,7);
// du stuff with a
Matrix b(5,7);
Matrix d=a+b;
d=a*5;
d[3][2]=1;

//but I can't do this:
double x=d[3][2];

//at this point I get this error:
```

`main.cpp:604:12: error: passing ‘const Matrix’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Matrix::Proxy Matrix::operator[](int)’ discards qualifiers`

Does anybody have any idea, how to fix this? :(

Implementation of my matrix class is here:

```
class Matrix {
public:

Matrix(int x, int y);
~Matrix(void);
//overloaded operators
Matrix operator+(const Matrix &matrix) const;  
Matrix operator-() const;
Matrix operator-(const Matrix &matrix) const; 
Matrix operator*(const double x) const; 
Matrix operator*(const Matrix &matrix) const; 

friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, Matrix& a);

class Proxy {
    Matrix& _a;
    int _i;
public:

    Proxy(Matrix& a, int i) : _a(a), _i(i) {

    }

    double& operator[](int j) {
        return _a._arrayofarrays[_i][j];
    }
};

Proxy operator[](int i) {
    return Proxy(*this, i);
}

// copy constructor

Matrix(const Matrix& other) : _arrayofarrays() {
    _arrayofarrays = new double*[other.x ];
    for (int i = 0; i != other.x; i++)
        _arrayofarrays[i] = new double[other.y];

    for (int i = 0; i != other.x; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j != other.y; j++)
            _arrayofarrays[i][j] = other._arrayofarrays[i][j];

    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
}
int x, y;
double** _arrayofarrays;
};
```

Comment: Your `const` version shouldn't return by reference.

Comment: @chris sorry..that was from previous version and it doesn't affect the rest of the code any way...I'll edit my post and delete it..if you've meant  that `double &operator[](int j) const`

Comment: Do you have a `const` version of `Matrix::operator[]`? That seems related to the error.

Comment: nope...this is all what I have in the definition of the class...wouldn't you mind to write and answer to show me, how should it look like in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have one `operator[]` signature:

```
Proxy operator[](Matrix *this, int i)
```

You're trying to call this:

```
Proxy operator[](const Matrix *, int)
```

The error is saying that in order to convert from `const Matrix *` to `Matrix *`, the `const` has to be discarded, which is bad. You should provide a `const` version inside your class:

```
Proxy operator[](int) const {...}
```

When inside your class, it gains a first parameter of `this`, and the `const` after the parameter list means that the first parameter will be a pointer to a constant object of your class, not a non-constant one.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation...Nevertheless when I add there `Proxy operator[](int i) const {     return Proxy(*this, i);   }`, then it generates this error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘Matrix::Proxy::Proxy(const Matrix&, int&)’` Wouldn't you mind to, edit your post and show me, how to handle this error? I'm quite new to C++ and all these stuff are really confusing to me :-/

Comment: @Dworza, I can't see a really easy way around it with the current code, but something like this should work if you only want to change the `Proxy` class (the main thing being that you could make the constructors take pointers and just pass `this`): http://liveworkspace.org/code/3MYYYt%240

Comment: Wouldn't you mind if I ask you another question related to this? I can't realize, how to get the value saved in the array, if I use your solution... when I want to print ie this: `cout<<matrix[0][0]<<endl;`, I get something like  2.08252e-317 ... and I want of course to get the real value... Is there some way, how to change the code in the definition of the class to make it work?

Comment: @Dworza, First of all, make sure your class follows the Rule of Three or Five (or use `std::vector` instead of a pointer). If it still happens after following that, make the smallest example possible that reproduces the error and post it in a new question.

Comment: the problem is, that I can't use `vector`... I'm very limited on includes :-/ Ok, I'll make a new question :)